# I downloaded the latest 3.0 alpha release. I cannot find ambient occlusion under world environment for cycles. Where it is?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, world, ambient-occlusion

In the previous versions, it was under the world tab. I downloaded latest release and now I cannot find it. This is the option I am looking for

[image]

This is from the latest release

[image: In the latest release]

Comment: do you mean the node ambient occlusion? if yes, just tap "shift-a" in the world shader nodes and search for it. It is there.

Comment: Wasn't it available as an option in previous versions? I am adding another image in question

Comment: yes, you are right. Looks like they deleted or removed the UI element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ambient Occlusion settings have been moved to *Render Properties > Light Paths > Fast GI Approximation*

[image: Render Properties > Light Paths > Fast GI Approximations]

Comment: And that's a good change IMHO. Good to note that Cycles doesn't "need" AO as raytracing does naturally all what AO is supposed to mimic. Technically, we "have AO" without the need of an additional AO effect. So it should be used either for stylized rendering, or very finely dosed.